# How can I make this menu using only anchor tag and css Not using ul and li?

Tags: html, css

How can I make this menu using only anchor tag and css Not using ul and li?

I have a Menu in Joomla whic by default creates the menu using `<ul> and <li>` tag, i want this to be done using `<a>` tag only. How can I achieve this?

Comment: A menu is a list of links. Why do you want your markup to be a pile of links stuck together instead of a list of links? What is wrong with having good markup and then styling it?

Comment: It was just asked to be done.. Even I am aware of that its the bad practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out...[My Example](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismackie/xXRUr/)

Comment: Ok What If I need this in Vertical Menu Format??

Answer (score 1):

use this css:

```
a
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10px; // whatever size
}
```

This will help you to show  tag as menu.